# VS2013 Express Test Explorer - how to expand all categories?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I'd like to view the tests in Test Explorer by class, but when I do so, even the ones that failed get hidden under the class categories, so I have to manually expand them all. I wind up just viewing them by status (pass/fail), but then they get all mushed together in one big long list. Is there any way to expand all the categories at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible unfortunately . You have to manually go and check them. But the test view by resharper gives a better overview.

Here you can see all the failed tests by number. Clicking on the failed tests tab(#67) on top will show just the failed tests (project-wise in this scenario) : [image]